# Reduce a multi-dimensional array to obtain sum/avg/min/max of the given array

Tags: javascript

I have an array as follows:

`a = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]`

I want to reduce it in such a way that as per user input function `f(array,ops)` it should output the result as follows:

`result = f(a,"sum"):`
`result = [6,8,10,12]`

```
const methods = {
        sum: (arr) => arr.reduce((total, v) => total + v, 0),
        avg: (arr) => methods.sum(arr) / arr.length,
        max: (arr) => Math.max.apply(null, arr),
        min: (arr) => Math.min.apply(null, arr),
      };
```

In the above way, I am planning to use it as:
`methods[methodname(array)];`

I want to call methods as shown below:

```
const value = Array(a.length);
a.forEach((elem,ind) => {
 value[0] = methods["sum"] // for all elem[0]
 value[1] = methods["sum"] // for all elem[1]
});
```

but I need to pass this for a multi-dimensional array. Can someone suggest a way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to transpose the array and map with one of your functions.

```js
const
    transpose = (r, a) => a.map((v, i) => [...(r[i] || []), v]),
    f = (array, key) => array
        .reduce(transpose, [])
        .map(methods[key]),
    methods = {
        sum: arr => arr.reduce((total, v) => total + v, 0),
        avg: arr => methods.sum(arr) / arr.length,
        max: arr => Math.max(...arr),
        min: arr => Math.min(...arr),
    },
    a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]];

console.log(...f(a, "sum")); // [6, 8,1 0, 12]
console.log(...f(a, "avg"));
```

Comment: Oh wow, thank you very much this is what I wanted!!!

Answer (score 0):

The accumulator function in your reduce has to deal with the inner array.

```js
var a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]

function sum(a) {
  return a.reduce((v, current) => {
    if (!v) return current.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
      v[i] += current[i];
    return v;
  }, undefined);
}

function avg(a) {
  return sum(a).map(x => x / a.length)
}

function max(a) {
  return a.reduce((v, current) => {
    if (!v) return current.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
      if (current[i] > v[i]) v[i] = current[i];
    return v;
  }, undefined);
}

function min(a) {
  return a.reduce((v, current) => {
    if (!v) return current.slice();
    for (let i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
      if (current[i] < v[i]) v[i] = current[i];
    return v;
  }, undefined);
}
console.log(sum(a))
console.log(avg(a))
console.log(max(a))
console.log(min(a))
```